# Dimension of ${U\cap W}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following question: Let $V$ be a vector spaces with dimension $n$. Let $U$ and $W$ be distinct  sub vector spaces of $V$ with dimension $n-1$. Find the dimension of ${U\cap W}$.
I proved that this dimension is between $n-2$ and $n-1$, so there are two options and I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: How did you prove that the dimension is between $n-2$ and $n-1$?

Comment: If two subspaces are distinct what does that tell you about their intersection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* If $U\cap W$ had dimension $n-1$, what could you say about $U\cap W$ and $U$? And about $U\cap W$ and $W$?